# Automatic store values in a json file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a JSON file called jsondb.json, I also have a file called index.html, in the index.html I have a input tag and a button.
So I want when ever I write something in the input tag then click the button, the value of the input will be save in my json file.

Index.HTML

```
<input placeholder='txt' id='txt' />

<button>save</button>
```

JSON FILE

```
{"txt":""}
```

Comment: How would you edit the JSON file?  I would do it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `input` and `button` in a `form` tag with and `action` attribute and a `method` attribute (assuming you are in php).
The `action` attribute refers to the page processing your results, and the `method` attribute is the action used to send your form data to the server.
In your action page, you need to get the parameters sent from your page with a `$_GET[param]` or `$_POST[param]` depending on the value of your `method` attribute.
Then you can write the value in a file with the `json_encode` function in PHP

For exemple:

`index.php` (note the .php)

```html
    <form action='somepage.php' method='GET'>
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="txt">
        <button type="submit">Save<button>
    </form>
```

`somepage.php`

```php
    //get the results
    $txt=$_GET['text']
    $array = ["text"=>$txt]
    
    //write the result in a text file
    $json = json_encode($array)
    $file=fopen('jsondb.json')
    fwrite($file,$json)
    fclose($file)
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Change `yourfile.txt` to `jsondb.json`.

Comment: So can't, only JavaScript do this ???, I want to use JavaScript only

Comment: You can use a nodejs backend if you want only javascript. In any case, you need a backend to process the request and write in the file.

Comment: Is not working,

Comment: You have to be a little more specific ;) This code is not working as is. It needs some adaptations to you fit your own situation. It's just the basic idea

Answer (score -1):

Well, this answer requires PHP but assuming you have a web server, this is my answer:

```js
var object = {
  txt : ""
}
function save(){
  var txt = $("#txt").text();
  object.txt = txt;
  savetofile(JSON.stringify(object));
}
function savetofile(txt){
         $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "process.php",
               data: {  
                        'file': txt
                 },
            });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder='txt' id='txt' />

<button onClick="save()">save</button>
```

process.php:

```
<?php
file_put_contents("jsondb.json", $_POST["file"]);
?>
```

Comment: So can't, only JavaScript do this ???, I want to use JavaScript only

Comment: Javascript is client-side. Client-side means that the client (aka the user) executes the script. To edit a file on the server, you need a backend script. PHP and my way use more javascript and less PHP.

Comment: You can use https://nodejs.org/ to use javascript only if you want.